# Webshere and JaxRS throw Error while run Application

Tags: java, jax-rs, websphere

I have the following code:

```
    @GET
@Path("/expats")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public List<Expat> alleExpat() {

    List<Expat> expatListe = new ArrayList<Expat>();
    DatebaseConnection();
    String query = "{CALL alleExpats()}";
    try {
        CallableStatement stmt = connection.prepareCall(query);
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {

            Expat expat = new Expat();
            expat.set_id(rs.getInt("_id"));
            expat.setCountry(rs.getString("country"));
            expat.setFirstname(rs.getString("firstname"));
            expat.setLastname(rs.getString("lastname"));
            expat.setSex(rs.getString("sex"));
            expat.setBis(rs.getDate("bis"));

            expatListe.add(expat);

        }

        rs.close();
        stmt.close();
    } catch (SQLException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        connection.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return expatListe;

}
```

if i trie to run this code i got the error:

> Problem with writing the data, class java.util.ArrayList, ContentType:
>   application/json

And if i run the URL in the browser i got :

> SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of
>   the JSON data

But nothing to see.
So, if i run change the appserver to tomact everything looks OK.
What must i change ?
I use Maven to download the jars (org.glassfish.jersey )

Comment: What WebSphere are you using -  traditional or Liberty and which version?

Comment: Liberty 18.0.03

Comment: Add `server.xml` or at least part with features. You may have conflict between features and embedded jars.